# What is the concept of God according to Vaisheshika school of philosophy?

Tags: gods, philosophy, shad-darshana, vaisheshika

Vaisheshika school is a school of philosophy in Hinduism that believes in God.

So what is the concept of God according to Vaisheshika.

Is God the creator of the universe?

Is he omnipotent, omnipresent and omniscient?

Comment: No bharatiya school of thoughts *believes* in god. Almost all school of thoughts have experienced god.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Vaisesika school is an early scientific school. It postulates the existence of atoms. God according to this school arranges the atoms in a manner that leads to the observed universe.

> It is in elaborating this cosmological scheme that the system
> postulates the **existence of God as the all-knowing Being**, who disposes
> the atoms in a manner required for the emergence of the world as we
> know it. **He does not create the atoms**, because they are eternal like
> Him. In other words, **He is only an efficient cause** possessing the will
> and intelligence required for bringing about the desired result. The
> variety characterizing the created world is determined by the past
> deeds of the beings that are to inhabit it. The doctrine accordingly
> associates a purpose with creation, viz. the reaping of the fruit of
> their karma by created beings and, we should add, the affording of
> opportunities in the case of man to emancipate himself. God is
> therefore not merely a creator; he is also the architect of the
> universe. .... **From the vastness of the universe and its extraordinary
> diversity, it is deduced that its author must possess infinite power
> as well as infinite wisdom.** An interesting feature about this theistic
> conception is that the supreme power is identified with Siva, one of
> the two Gods who as we have seen claimed the faith and devotion of the
> pious Indian in post-Vedic times.

**The Essentials of Indian Philosophy, Chapter 4, by M. Hiriyanna**